# ASP.NET Core Web API - User unable to Login after Password Reset

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

Password reset is not working.

In ASP.NET Core Web API using Entity Framework with user Identity DB,  I want the user to be able to reset his password himself.

The user will just enter only his email. Then the system will auto-generated the new password, and update the old one in the database with the auto-generated one. The new password is then sent to the user.

However, when user tries to log in, he got the error:

> Invalid Credentials

Then I observed that the `PasswordHash` column in the `AspNetUser` table is not updated. It still remains the same.

Code - model:

```
public class MerchantResetPasswordDto
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

`UserResetUserPasswordByEmailAsync` method:

```
public async Task<Response<string>> UserResetUserPasswordByEmailAsync(MerchantResetPasswordDto model)
{
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        try
        {
            var response = new Response<string>();
            var merchantUserName = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers
                                             .Where(u => u.Email == model.Email)
                                             .Select(m => m.UserName)
                                             .FirstOrDefault();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(merchantUserName))
            {
                _logger.Information("User Not Found");
                response.Message = "User Not Found";
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                response.Successful = false;
            }
            else
            {
                var user = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers
                                     .First(u => u.Email == model.Email);

                var userByName = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(merchantUserName);
                var loggedUserRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(userByName);
                var loggedUserRoleName = loggedUserRole[0].ToString();
                auditUserId = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == userByName.UserName).Select(m => m.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                var userIsActive = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == userByName.UserName).Select(m => m.IsActive).FirstOrDefault();

                var rng = new Random();

                ulong randomNumber = rng.NextULong(1000, 9999);

                var merchantPassword = "@Password" + randomNumber.ToString();
                user.PasswordHash = _userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, merchantPassword);

                if (loggedUserRoleName == "Merchant" || loggedUserRoleName == "MerchantUser")
                {
                    if ((bool)userIsActive)
                    {
                        //var userToken = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(userByEmail);
                        _logger.Information($"user Token: {userToken}");
                        //var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(userByEmail, userToken, merchantPassword);
                        var updateResult = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                        _logger.Information($"result: {updateResult}");
                        if (updateResult.Succeeded)
                        {
                            // Audit Trail: Successful
                            var audit = new AuditReport()
                            {
                                AuditType = "Password Reset",
                                ActionPerformed = $"Successfully Reset User Password: {userByName.UserName}",
                                UserId = auditUserId,
                                SystemIpAddress = ipAddress.ToString(),
                            };

                            await _unitOfWork.AdminAuditReports.InsertAsync(audit);
                            await _unitOfWork.Save();

                            var mailBody = await EmailBodyBuilder.GetMerchantUserSelfPasswordResetEmailBody(userByName, merchantPassword, emailTempPath: "wwwroot/files/Html/MerchantUserSelfResetPasswordEmail.html");
                            var mailRequest = new MailRequest()
                            {
                                Subject = "Password Reset Notification",
                                Body = mailBody,
                                ToEmail = userByName.Email
                            };

                            bool emailResult = await _mailService.SendEmailAsync(mailRequest);

                            if (emailResult)
                            {
                                _logger.Information("Password Reset Successfully Done");
                                response.Message = "Password Reset Successfully Done";
                                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                                response.Successful = true;
                                response.Data = "Password Reset Successfully Done!";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                _logger.Information("Email Service not available");
                                response.Message = "Email Service not available";
                                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                                response.Successful = false;
                                response.Data = "Email Service not available!";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _logger.Error("Failed to update user.");
                            response.Message = "Failed to update user.";
                            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                            response.Successful = false;
                            response.Data = "Failed to update user.";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _logger.Error("Unauthorized");
                        response.Data = null;
                        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                        response.Message = "Unauthorized";
                        response.Successful = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.Error("Unauthorized");
                    response.Data = null;
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                    response.Message = "Unauthorized";
                    response.Successful = false;
                }
            }

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = ex.Message ?? "An error occurred while resetting the user password.";
            _logger.Error("Failed to Reset User Password: " + errorMessage);

            var errorResponse = new Response<string>
            {
                Successful = false,
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                Message = "An error occurred while resetting the user password.",
                Data = null
            };

            return errorResponse;
        }
    };
}
```

Kindly help resolve it.

Comment: Why are you not using userManager.ResetPasswordAsync ?

Comment: I think this is not the proper way for reset password as mentioned above. The possible problem is that the password hash comparison in login process is not same as hashing process during reset so the login process comparing inequal hashes.

Comment: @RosdiKasim - What else can I do, because there is no token confirmation.

Comment: You can generate the token yourself, then use that token to reset password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly there is some weirdness in your logic and a lot of extra querying against the database which is setting off some alarm bells. For instance:

```
var merchantUserName = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers
    .Where(u => u.Email == model.Email)
    .Select(m => m.UserName)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

then follow up queries...

```
var user = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers
    .First(u => u.Email == model.Email);

auditUserId = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == userByName.UserName).Select(m => m.Id).FirstOrDefault();
var userIsActive = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == userByName.UserName).Select(m => m.IsActive).FirstOrDefault();
```

Firstly, this code implies that Email is unique. If it doesn't have a unique constraint then it would be better to use `Single`. When querying against in-memory sets, `First` is preferable, but again so long as you trust the criteria is unique. Against the database `Single` performs a `TOP(2)` query which guards against duplicates. Since you fetch a user you don't need to keep going to the DB. Again this is also implying that UserName has a unique constraint as well.  This could all be replaced with:

```
var user = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers
    .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Email);

if (user == null)
{
    _logger.Information("User Not Found");
    response.Message = "User Not Found";
    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    response.Successful = false;
    return response;
}

var userByName = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName);
var loggedUserRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(userByName);
var loggedUserRoleName = loggedUserRole[0].ToString();
var auditUserId = user.Id;
var userIsActive = user.IsActive;
```

We load the user once and that has the information we need. No need to go back to the DB and risk pulling details from a different user.

The next warning flag I see is a mix of references between _dbContext and some _unitOfWork. I don't see a correlation here, where there is a `_unitOfWork.Save()` which appears to be related to some of the logging, I don't see anything like an `await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` to save the user loaded and tracked by the DbContext.

So the first two things I'd look to eliminate is the possibility that a different user than you intend was selected and updated, then also that the changes weren't actually committed because there was no `SaveChanges` call.